# Eliminate MultiSite Network Splogs

Tags: multisite

Are there any plugins that can delete splogs from a MultiSite Network? I have been looking for quite a while but can not find any plugins that can delete splogs from a MultiSite Network. Although I have been able to find plugins to prevent spam, that is not what I want here.

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2):

Anti-Splog from WPMUDev looks like a pretty strong tool for deleting spam blogs: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/anti-splog

Answer (score 1):

WangGuard is an awesome plugin. It is free for personal use but for commercial use, you have to pay.
http://wangguard.com/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't [Akismet](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/) work for WPMU?